# Make combination not in alphabetical order

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to make combinations of value using `combinations` function in `gtools` package.

For example, I have vector `cat_var`

`cat_var<-c("James","Ariana","Kevin","Bob")`

Then, I want to make

`James Ariana
 James Kevin
 James Bob
 Ariana Kevin
 Ariana Bob
 Kevin Bob`

However, when I used `combinations` function, combination was made by alphabetical order, like

```
> cat_var<-c("James","Ariana","Kevin","Bob")
> combinations(n = length(cat_var), r = 2, v = cat_var, repeats.allowed = FALSE)
     [,1]     [,2]   
[1,] "Ariana" "Bob"  
[2,] "Ariana" "James"
[3,] "Ariana" "Kevin"
[4,] "Bob"    "James"
[5,] "Bob"    "Kevin"
[6,] "James"  "Kevin"
```

How to make combinations with pre-defined order?

Comment: You can use `combn(cat_var, 2)` why do you need a package ?

Comment: Thanks. I copied the code on Github. I didn't know `combn` function.